# CX_Oracle import Error for libclntsh.so.12.1

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, importerror, cx-oracle

I have **Oracle 11g** configured in my `Ubuntu 16.04` and its working perfectly fine.

Previously I tried to install `Oracle 12c`, which was giving some errors so I removed it and install 11g.

Now, my problem is that when I try to use `import cx_Oracle` in `python`, it gives import error for `libclntsh.so.12.1`.

Here is the whole output:

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My .bashrc file has these entries:

```
export PATH="/home/marvin/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Why is it still trying to take `Oracle 12c`? Is there is some error in 11g configuration or in 12c uninstall?

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling `cx_oracle` via `pip`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the ldd command on the cx_Oracle shared library file that it is trying to load. You should be able to use the "imp" module to find the location of the cx_Oracle module that is being loaded, as in the following:

```
import imp
imp.find_module("cx_Oracle")
```

You may discover that the module it is trying to load is found somewhere you didn't expect!

Also, when you run the command to pip install cx_Oracle confirm that it is actually compiling and what files are being linked.

I hope one of those tips are able to help you figure out what the problem is with your configuration.

Comment: finally fixed it! Thanks man. On using `ldd cx_Oracle.so` I had this output: `linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007ffeb4dc3000)` `libclntsh.so.12.1 => not found ...` Then, I uninstalled reinstalled `oracle 11g` completely again. cleaned my `pip` cache and installed `cx_Oracle` package again. Now everything works fine. Problem was with **pip cache** as it was taking previously fetched cx_oracle which was causing error all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to debug:

**1. find file to do ldd on**

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.find_module("cx_Oracle")
(<_io.BufferedReader name='/opt/data-tools/Anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>, '/opt/data-tools/Anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', ('.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'rb', 3))
```

**2. do ldd**

```
    ldd /opt/data-tools/Anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

      libclntsh.so.12.1 => not found
```

3. find where is libclntsh.so.12.1(*or whatever is missing for your case*).
4. make sure dir which contains libclntsh.so.12.1 is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If it is not in the path, add it.

   ```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/lib/
   ```

**5. Uninstall and install**

```
    /opt/data-tools/Anaconda/bin/pip uninstall cx_Oracle==5.1.3
    export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0 &&  /opt/data-tools/Anaconda/bin/pip install cx_Oracle==5.1.3 --no-cache-dir
```

**6. check ldd**

```
    ldd /opt/data-tools/Anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd89ca2000)
      libclntsh.so.12.1 => /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 (0x00007f1a3a4ba000)
```

Comment: It might be time to update; the current version of cx_Oracle is 7, but you are installing 5.1.3

Comment: One of our old code base does not work with latest cx_Oracle :(